# Get request data in jQuery's AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say I make a Dictionary app, where I check if some word exists or not. I have a text input and a button:

```
<input type="text" id="word">
<input type="button" id="button">
```

I'd like the server to respond with either `1` (valid word) or `0` (invalid word).

In my jQuery script, I send an AJAX request:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php?word=" + $("#word").val(),
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (isValid, textStatus, xhr) {
            // Can I read the URL from the xhr to know which word was the request for?
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, when the response comes back, I no longer know which word is it for. I know I could attach the word to the server's response, but I'm very curious if it can be done other way.

I'm pretty sure I can just attach this piece of information to the raw XHR and then read it in success callback, but my question is: does XHR in success callback contain infromation about request's URL and data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the jQuery xhr object in beforeSend with anything you want then access it in success or then() or done() callbacks

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://httpbin.org/get',
  data:{foo:'bar'},
  beforeSend:function(jQxhr){
    jQxhr.something='another thing';
  },
  success:function(res,statusText,jQxhr){
    console.log('"Something" in success() ', jQxhr.something)
  }
}).then(function(res,statusText,jQxhr){
    console.log('"Something" in then() ', jQxhr.something)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned in my question that I'm aware of that possibility. Is it the only way to read the URL in XHR? Doesn't jQuery store it somewhere in XHR after sending a request?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You know what you send before hand

Comment: Sure I do, but it would be quite nice to have. Asynchronous code is different philosophy, so any information like that is precious.

Comment: Fine but that's why jQuery exposes the object in `beforeSend`

Comment: In other words - if I send letters to my mom and dad with the question if they love me (yes / no) and they write me back, I know who I wrote to, but I don't know who is it who replied.

Comment: OK I believe you are right that there's no request infomation like that.

Comment: New `fetch` api might give you more of what you want ...not sure. Just think you are over complicating a not complicated problem

Comment: It does! I just checked it out. It's as simple as `fetch('game.txt').then(function(response) {console.log(response.url);});`. Hah! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    var word = $("#word").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php?word=" + word,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(word);
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: Removed from Robo Robok comment, in which he is correct.

Comment: Success function returns 3 values. And yeah, I know it can be done this way too, but for some reason I don't like to depend on the variable scope.

Comment: @RoboRobok What's wrong with the variable scope? It is encapsulated in a closure

Comment: OK, let's say I tolerate it. But can I read this URL? This is truly a question for personal education :D